# TypeScript: Discriminated Union with empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union

I have the following type `User`:

```
type User = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
} | {};
```

So essentially a user can be an object with name and email properties, or the empty object.

When I try to check *which* of the two a given user object is, TypeScript shows an error.

```
if (user.name) { // ERROR
    // do something if user object is populated
}
```

Specifically the above code throws the error:

```
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'PrismicImage'.
Property 'url' does not exist on type '{}'
```

Is it possible to have a discriminated union where one of the interfaces is the empty object?

Answer (score 4):

A discriminated union (as the term is commonly understood in TypeScript) is a union in which there is a *discriminant* property that exists on every member of the union with a different value.  So a union including `{}` is, by definition, not a discriminated union.  If you are willing to change your design to use a discriminated union, everything should work.

Re your current design: In general, a TypeScript object type includes any object that has *at least* the specified properties.  That means `{}` is effectively the type of any object, and your `User` type just simplifies to `{}`.  There is no (reasonable) way to express the type of an object with no properties; [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) might add one.  You'll have to cast your object before you can test the `name` property, and even after you test the property, I'm not aware of any way to make TypeScript automatically know that the `email` property also exists.  You could at least define a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to hide all the mess in one function.

Answer (score 4):

You can us `in` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator

```
if (user.name) { // error
    user // typeof user is User | {}
    user.name // error
    user.email // error 
}

if ('name' in user) {
    user // ok, typeof user is User
    user.name  // string 
    user.email // string
}
```

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqA7AQwFsIAuKOYRASzwHMBubXCIg6gG3MpvqYF9MmACYQAxhwKJoANylQArgkTl4SKAB8M-JpmoAzKAAolSAHSESASgzMcp5AHpHUJIgD2iADQ5Qkd4YOqNqasMp2isoWxNDOrogeiBEOZqzsHFBxbp5QmIJ6hkYA5JYQRVC0kUg2WLhVTi7uANY+fhAB9cFqSXUppThxPLR0ub1RaZyZLkP0eUA)